# ng-repeat on objects to create drop down

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

My object looks like:

```
var models = {
      "Test1":{
              "name":"Test1",
              "members":
                  {
                    "T1":{//some more properties},
                    "T2":{//some more properties}
              }
      }
      "Test2":{
              "name":"Test2",
              "members":
                  {
                    "T1":{//some more properties},
                    "T2":{//somemore properties}
              }
      }
}
```

Provided, user selects a property of object *models*, I want to display the members property of that selected property of models object in a drop down.
Eg. if user selects Test1 property, drop down should be populated with T1 and T2.

Any suggestions regarding question clarity are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can't change your object, in your HTML you can have:

```
<div ng-repeat="model in models">
  <div>
    <p ng-click="toggleVisibility(model.name)">Name: {{model.name}}</p>
    <div ng-repeat="member in model.members" ng-if="model.visibility">
      <p>Member Name: {{getMemberName(model.name, $index)}} </p>
      <p>Member properties: {{getMemberProperties(model.name, $index)}} </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And on your AngularJS Controller:

```
$scope.toggleVisibility = function (entry) {
  $scope.models[entry].visibility = !$scope.models[entry].visibility;
};

$scope.getMemberName = function (entry, $index) {
  return Object.keys($scope.models[entry].members)[$index];
};

$scope.getMemberProperties = function (entry, $index) {
  var key = Object.keys($scope.models[entry].members)[$index];
  return $scope.models[entry].members[key];
};
```

EDIT: Change the answer to fit the requirements.

Comment: Sorry, can't. Architect won't allow me.

Comment: It works, but as I said software architect won't allow me to change the object.

Comment: The fiddle in the previous comment is using your object structure. Can you check it again if it works for you?